# AWS EFS Throughput not exceeding 1MB

Tags: amazon-web-services, throughput

I hope you can assist with a question around EFS throughput that I am seeing on our AWS services.

I have setup an EFS filesystem which I have mounted on 2 x EC2 instances. Originally, I had it configured as burstable throughput.

When looking at the MeteredIOBytes metric, the maximum throughput never exceeds 1.05M. I thought it might be because I am not using much space on EFS and as I understand it, when on burstable throughput, the throughput increases as you use more GBs.

I then tried changing the EFS to provisioned throughput of 5MB, but even after doing this, the MeteredIOBytes metric never exceeds 1.5MB.

[efs1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6knn.png)

In both burstable and provisioned mode, when comparing the maximum MeteredIOBytes with PermittedThroughput, the MeteredIOBytes is way below Permitted.

[efs2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aJwa.png)

I am only using 3GB of storage space on EFS.

Is there a setting I am missing to increase the throughput beyond 1.5MB?

Thanks